# How to Start Bazaar Explorer?

Tags: bazaar

[Contributing to Free Software Projects Made Easy](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/tutorials/foss-contribute.html) states:

> Start Bazaar Explorer.

but does not describe how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, as described in [Linux Installation -- Bazaar Explorer](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/install-linux.html):

```
bzr explorer
```